# Need help/guidance on jenkins/plot plugin setup and configure

Tags: xml, csv, plugins, jenkins, plot

I am new to Jenkins and need some help to configure it so that it can display my test results in pie chart.

I have written a cmdline tool which can run multiple tests. Let's say my tool ran 10 tests, 7 passed, 1 skipped, and 2 failed. I want to configure jenkins to display a pie chart whose 70% area is green (passes), 10% yellow and 20% red. I have configure jenkins to run this tool and I have already installed plot-plugin. I also made some examples found on-line working.

However, I don't know what kind of csv and/or xml file to generate. I need help to show me what kind of format in csv and xml. I also need help to show me how to configure "post build actions" in jenkins. A screen shot is highly appreciated.

Lastly, I don't even know if I am on the right track. The tool is ready to generate any formats I want. And I have to use jenkins. But I am not sure whether the plot-plugin is the right one to use? If not, please tell me what other plugins I should use.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Or maybe I should dashboard view? I read this page: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View but still have no idea how to configure it. I don't even know how to get the dropdowns shown under "Configure dashboard view" on the page.

Comment: Maybe I should restate my original question. I have a tool to run a smoke test which is to install a piece of sw on multiple hosts. And my tool can keep track the number of passed/failed/skipped installations. I want to display the test statistics in a pie chart on jenkins. What plug-ins am I supposed to use? What kind of data file am I supposed to provide? Please show me step by step with data file format and the screen shots. Thanks!!